# standing during gelilah

Tags: torah-service, sefer-torah, standing-sitting, hagbah-gelilah

I've noticed that people usually stay standing after hagbah until the Torah is dressed, even after the magbia sits down. Is there a mekor for this practice, or is it muttar to sit once the magbia holding the sefer Torah is seated?

Comment: Once the Torah is held by someone who is sitting one can sit.

Comment: I stay standing because the hagbah may stand up again in the shuffle (maybe to help the gelilah).

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman I don't remember ever seeing the _magbiah_ stand again to help with the _g'lila_. I have sometimes, however, seen him stand to put the _sefer_ elsewhere (some synagogues have designated spots for the _s'farim_ after _g'lila_, and IIRC some place them on the table for the _haftara_), to pass it to another, or to sit elsewhere.

Comment: @msh210 a shul I grew up going to is indeed careful to put the sefer on the table for the haftara to allow people to sit for the haftara while being strict that a sefer held by a seated person is not sufficiently "at rest"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mishnah Berurah (146:17) explains the ruling of the Mechaber that one doesn't need to stand for keriat ha-torah, because when the Torah is "in its place" one doesn't need to stand: א"צ לעמוד וכו' - ואפילו העומדים על הבימה דא"צ לעמוד מפני ס"ת אלא כשאדם נושאה אבל כשמונחת במקומה א"צ...וכן אפילו כשאחד תופסה בידו כגון בעת שקורין ההפטרה כיון שהוא יושב במקומו א"צ לעמוד לפניה. The Sha'ar ha-Tziyun explains further: ובפרי מגדים כתב דאפילו הוא עומד עמה (כגון בעת שמזכיר החזן נשמות), גם כן אינו מחוייב אז לקום לפניה, כיון שהחזן עומד עמה במקום אחד, ולפי זה הוא הדין בעת שפותחין הארון, כי הלא בכל זה במקומה מונחת. והעולם נוהגין בכל זה לעשות הידור לתורה ולעמוד. ועיין באליה רבה שדעתו, דבעת הגבהה מחוייבין הכל לעמוד אף שהיא ברשות אחרת, וטעמו דהרי הוא מגביה להראותה לעם ומחוייבין לכבדה. According to this reasoning, one would not have to stand during gelilah. This halakhah is stated explicitly by the Maharam Schick ([Orach Chaim no. 65](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1494&pgnum=46)) which I found cited in the [Leket Kemach ha-Chadash](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?84209&%24201310190014796).

Comment: Until the outer cover is placed on the sefer Torah, the *magbia* is logistically compelled to hold the sefer Torah in a manner that might be described as not at rest. If this is in fact not considered a resting position, people should stand until the *magbia* can reposition the sefer Torah into its resting position.

Comment: Well, given that the Maharam Schick says that he is discussing "בדין אי חייבין בשעה שאוחזין ספר תורה מזמן גלילה עד הכנסתה למקומה" and never makes such a chilluk, it seems like he does not consider that type of holding to be "not at rest".

Comment: @Malper I just read the Maharam Shik. The phrasing you mention is relevant to the lenient position that he takes. His interpretation of the stringent position is less clear, though. He writes (paraphrased): "When the Sefer Torah is at rest or being held while sitting, whether in it's place or not (in the case of sitting, this means whether the person is sitting in his intended final spot, or whether he is sitting down while pausing on the way to his final spot), whether the Sefer Torah is resting in a vertical or horizontal resting position, everyone agrees that people don't need to stand."